# Get the value of an XML Element as a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, soap, linq-to-xml

I am using XDocument to load an xml and trying to retrieve the value (eg. "-1" under the "RCode" within the `<ContextValue>` element.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dsContext xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ttContext>
    <ContextName>RCode</ContextName>
    <ContextValue>-1</ContextValue>
  </ttContext>
</dsContext>
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dsMessage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Messages>
    <MessageNum>CA9001</MessageNum>
    <MessageText>ERROR: End date &gt; Start date. (CA:25)</MessageText>
  </Messages>
</dsMessage>
```

I have tried the following

```
XDocument x = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
if (x.Root.Elements().Any())
{

string id = "RCode";

XElement codevalue = (from xml2 in x.Descendants("dsContext").Descendants("ttContext") 
                    where xml2.Element("ContextName").Value == id
                    select xml2).FirstOrDefault();
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + codevalue.ToString() + "');", true);
}
```

It returned back "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
How do I get the value back as a string or int so I can use it?

Thank you for helping me out

Comment: Your xml is malformed. Can you make sure it's correct?

Comment: There no `Descendants("dsContext")`, because "dsContext" is a root. Try only: `from xml in x.Descendants("ttContext")`

Comment: Your results is getting a null which you cannot cast to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can target the `ContextValue` directly from the doc's descendants. Then from there you can get the element from that, and get its value.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("foo.xml");
var element = doc.Descendants("ContextValue").FirstOrDefault();
var value = element.Value;
Console.WriteLine(value); // -1
```

Note, your xml example is malformed - not sure if you intended it to be that way or not.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick response. Im not sure what you mean by malformed, sorry. I got XML through a SOAP response, and that was what it returned. I saved it as a string and parse it in XDocument. The var value returned "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: What is the value of `x` in your example when you debug it? Is it valid?

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about checking if x is vaild, hence I place a try, catch XML exception and an if else statement to check if x has any elements before executing the parse

Comment: Don’t use a try catch. For now let’s see the errors so we know what they are. Also. Your code above isn’t as you describe (missing try catch). Remove the try catch and check the error.